# Flurry Analytics Info

Tags: iphone, ios, flurry

Hi ,

I have some questions about Flurry Analytics. My App has a TabbarController and I wouldn't want to track all pageView.

1. I have started my FlurrySesion in App delegate. Should I end the session on AppInBackground or when the app terminates?
2. I have suuccessfully track log eveent, but how can I get it End Event With time?
3. When does the number of user increase on flurry analytics server?
4. How can I track

   - New Users
   - Active Users
   - Sessions
   - Session Length
   - Frequency of Use
   - User Retention
   - Page views – Need to track Page view data
   - Age – need to track age data
   - Gender – need to track gender data
   - Geography

Should it to be do manually or dynamically?

Thanks.
 -Keyur

Answer (score 3):

Flurry will only log all page views when connected to a navigationController, not a tabBarController. And you would have to add that if you wanted to track it, it does not come standard.

Sending the session data is personal preference. If you don't have much going on, no reason to override the defaults.

To track a timed event, you need to call the -endTimedEvent method with the matching name to capture the time correctly.

```
[FlurryAnalytics logEvent:@"MyCustomEvent" timed:YES];

// do stuff

[FlurryAnalytics endTimedEvent:@"MyCustomEvent" withParameters:nil]; // set parameters if you have any
```

If you do not call endTimedEvent, all events with timed:YES will end at the end of the session.

New users are captured automatically from the default data the Flurry sends. It will not capture the personal information like age, uniqueID, or location. But it will give you an accurate representation of how many new users are using your app. If you want to add further tracking, you will have to add that in to Flurry extra.

Flurry allows you to add userId, age, gender, and location in addition to the device and carrier information it collects anyway. You have to set these manually and are listed in the API documentation.

Hope this addresses all your questions.

Comment: what if i want end all my previous events which are running in one go without depending on the event name?

Comment: @user431791 , Please see the current answer, may be you will get solution from it. :-)

Comment: Current Flurry docs indicate it can automatically track a tab bar.

Comment: Probably now. This answer is over 2 years old.

Answer (score 2):

1. You should do it when you want to stop tracking the events
2. `[FluryAnalytics logEvent:eventName timed:YES]` should do it
3. Track it on flurry dashboard.
4. Track it on flurry dashboard